# Validating file or folder location in azure-storage-blob using simple http call

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

We have a requirement to validate the folder or a file location which is there in azure-blob-storage container.

Example folder path: wasbs://@.blob.core.windows.net/
Example file path: wasbs://@.blob.core.windows.net//

Would like to validate the file or the folder exists or not before proceeding with my business logic.

Is there any way I can validate the paths using URI? instead of going with storage packages.

Note: We are not allowed to use SAS token to access the storage path.
But, we can go with storage key or connection string to connect to storage account from application code.

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful for you? Please mark as an answer to help the community find relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wasb is the hdfs compatible API on top of Azure blob storage, if you use HTTP:// , you could perhaps check on the path and the HTTP response you get, 404 probably path/file doesn't exist, 200, file path exists. I hope this helps.

**Update:**
Thanks @Gaurav for the insightful comment,I also added an example on checking the blob status in python, you can do so in other languages as well, you can just plugin the needed information: Storage account name, key, container name, blob name, and you'll get back a boolean value if the blob exists or not:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='', account_key='')

def blob_exists():

        container_name = ""
        blob_name = ""

        exists=(block_blob_service.exists(container_name, blob_name))
        return exists
blobstat = blob_exists()
print(blobstat)
```

Comment: Adam...You will also get a 404 error back if you simply try to perform a `GET` operation on the Blob URL if the blob container's ACL is `Private`. Better alternative would be to perform an authorized `GET` request. Doing something like `Exists` or `GetBlobProperties` in .Net SDK should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I added an example in python to check if blob exists, should be easily changed to .Net based on customer's need.